# Dummy variables code for intervals in R

Tags: r, intervals

I have a distance variable (in meters)of properties from a specific source, created via QGIS in my subset of data.

I want to create dummy intervals as follows in R:

> 0-100, 101-200, 201-300, 301-400 & 401-500

I have coded as follows, in order to include all properties within any of the following intervals:

```
data$Distance_100<-0
data$Distance_100[data$Distance<100]<-1

data$Distance_200<-0
data$Distance_200[data$Distance>=101&data$Distance<200]<-1

data$Distance_300<-0
data$Distance_300[data$Distance>=201&data$Distance<300]<-1

data$Distance_400<-0
data$Distance_400[data$Distance>=301&data$Distance<400]<-1

data$Distance_500<-0
data$Distance_500[data$Distance>=401&data$Distance<500]<-1
```

Seems to be something wrong in the coding. It won't assign all properties lying in the interval with the correct coding it seems. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Besides the usefull answers so far, look at `findInterval`, and do learn to search before posting questions on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `cut` function to create a single categorical variable for the intervals:

```
data$DistanceCut5 = cut(data$Distance, breaks=c(0,100,200,300,400,500))
```

If you're doing regression, you don't need to code separate dummy variables. `R` will take care of that for you if you enter `DistanceCut5` into the regression formula.

Also, take a look at the help for `cut` so you can see how to change the category labels (using the `labels` argument) and how to determine whether the right or left side of the intervals is closed (using the `right` argument).

In addition, if any values of `Distance` are greater than 500, cut will set the category label to `NA` (missing). If you want to ensure that all values of `Distance` have a category value in `DistanceCut5`, then make sure that the range between the lowest and highest values of `levels` includes all the values in `Distance`.

One other style comment: `data` is actually a function in `R`, so it's best not to get in the habit of using it as a name for your data frames.

Comment: `model.matrix(~ DistanceCut5 + 0, data=data)` will then give you the broken apart columns if required.

Comment: Thank you, @eipi10! Just one (stupid) quesition. 0-100 interval seems not to be estimated? just starts with
 
DistanceCut(100,200]
DistanceCut(200,300] etc. so is that 101-200 and 201-300 ? So it doesn't overlap. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean your data frame or is this the result of a regression analysis? If the latter, then `(0,100]` is the base category and the other category coefficients are relative to the base category. This is just like traditional dummy coding. You always have to leave out one category if you want to include the intercept in the regression.

Comment: One other thing: Since the categories in this case are ordered, you should set `ordered_result=TRUE` in the `cut` function. That will make `R` treat `DistanceCut5` as an ordered factor rather than a nominal factor.